# Android ViewPager in Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager

I am problem with swipe image view.

I use this [library](https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator)

And I need import in my project but I have a problem.

I want use in every row in listview. But in my listviewAdapter is highlighteed this code (code which doing swipe imageview) [more accurate `getSupportFragmentManager()`  ]

Code which use from library

```
Fragment demoFragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, AnimationFragment.class.getName());
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, demoFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                @Override public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                }
            });
```

I thing so Need AppCompatActivity but how I get appcompatactivity if I in listview adapter?

Or how i get something like here

[image: I need something like this]

ListviewAdapter
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Activity activity;
List<Kon> listKone;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Bitmap bitmapOriginal;

ProgressBar progressBar;


public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, List<Kon> listKone) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listKone = listKone;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listKone.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return listKone.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item,null);

    TextView txtUser = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
    TextView txtBorn = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_born);
    TextView txtcena = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_cena);
    TextView txtplemeno = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_plemeno);
    ImageView imgHorse=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageHorse);
    ImageView imgHorseB=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageHorseB);
    progressBar= (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2) ;

    txtUser.setText(listKone.get(i).getName());
    txtBorn.setText(listKone.get(i).getNarodenie());
    txtcena.setText(listKone.get(i).getCena());
    txtplemeno.setText(listKone.get(i).getPlemeno());
    // Then later, when you want to display image

    if (listKone.get(i).getCestaObrazok()!=null) {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(listKone.get(i).getCestaObrazok(), imgHorse);

        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgHorse.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
           bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
        }



        while ((drawable==null)||(bitmap==null)) {
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(listKone.get(i).getCestaObrazok(), imgHorse); // Default options will be used
            //ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(listKone.get(i).getCestaObrazok(), imgHorseB); // Default options will be used
            // ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(listKone.get(i).getCestaObrazok(), imgHorseB); // Default options will be used

            drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgHorse.getDrawable();
            try {
                bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
            } catch (NullPointerException e){
             //   Toast.makeText(activity, "drawable null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //  imgHorseB.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        Bitmap blurred = blurRenderScript(activity, bitmap, 25);
        imgHorseB.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgHorseB.setImageBitmap(blurred);
    }
    return itemView;
}
```

Thanks If you need more info I will here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use this library: https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator

It is very simple. In the XML:

```
<me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>
```

In the java class:

```
ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
viewpager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter(listKone,i,activity));
indicator.setViewPager(viewpager);
```